# Hybris - I can't start the server due to some unknown error

Tags: solr, ant, sap-commerce-cloud

I tried doing ant build, ant clean all, SVN checkout a clean one and redownload a copy on my work's file server. It works fine on other machines (my workmates) but to me it can't seem to start after hybrisserver.bat and I can't find the problem.

I think this might be related to the Solr server.

This is some of the console messages that appears:

```
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.startup(Registry.java:422)
>         at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.startRegistry(H
> ybrisContextLoaderListener.java:237)
>         at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.doInitWebApplic
> ationContext(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:135)
>         at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicat
> ionContext(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:125)
>         at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitiali
> zed(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
>         at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.contextInitiali
> zed(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:80)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContex
> t.java:5016)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContex
> t.java:5524)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
> java:1575)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
> java:1565)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
> java:1142)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
> .java:617)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] [HybrisContextFactory] Initializing <<global>>
> Spr ing ApplicationContext took: (22.52 I¼s)
> de.hybris.platform.core.UninstantiableCoreApplicationContextException:
> Error cre ating Spring application context.
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doStartupSafe(AbstractTenant.j
> ava:728)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doStartUp(AbstractTenant.java:
> 658)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.assureTenantStarted(Registry.java:63
> 9)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.activateTenant(Registry.java:700)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.setCurrentTenant(Registry.java:544)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.activateMasterTenant(Registry.java:6
> 07)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.startup(Registry.java:422)
>         at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.startRegistry(H
> ybrisContextLoaderListener.java:237)
>         at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.doInitWebApplic
> ationContext(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:135)
>         at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicat
> ionContext(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:125)
>         at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitiali
> zed(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
>         at de.hybris.platform.spring.HybrisContextLoaderListener.contextInitiali
> zed(HybrisContextLoaderListener.java:80)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContex
> t.java:5016)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContex
> t.java:5524)
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
> java:1575)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.
> java:1565)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
> java:1142)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
> .java:617)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Context hybris Global C
> ontext Factory  couldn't  be created correctly due to, Error creating
> bean with name 'defaultSolrServerService' defined in class path
> resource [global-solrserve r-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method
> failed; nested exception is de.hybris.p
> latform.solrserver.SolrServerException: Error while executing Solr
> start command  for instance: [name: default, port: 8983]
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFacto
> ry.java:317)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.bui
> ldSelf(HybrisContextFactory.java:189)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.bui
> ld(HybrisContextFactory.java:175)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstanceCached(H
> ybrisContextHolder.java:134)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstance(HybrisC
> ontextHolder.java:113)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getAppCtxFactory(HybrisCo
> ntextHolder.java:164)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getApplicationInstance(Hy
> brisContextHolder.java:90)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.createCoreApplicationContext(A
> bstractTenant.java:686)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doStartupSafe(AbstractTenant.j
> ava:724)
>         ... 20 more Error creating Spring application context. Shutting down hybris platform since t he system cannot be used without
> working Spring context... shutting down hybris registry.. INFO 
> [Thread-1] [HybrisContextFactory] Initializing <<global>> Spring
> Applicati onContext took: (16.99 I¼s) ERROR [Thread-1] [JMXBeanLoader]
> Can't unregister jmxbeans on shutdown of the te nant <<master>>
> org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Context hybris Global
> Context Fact ory  couldn't  be created correctly due to, Error
> creating bean with name 'defau ltSolrServerService' defined in class
> path resource [global-solrserver-spring.xm l]: Invocation of init
> method failed; nested exception is de.hybris.platform.sol
> rserver.SolrServerException: Error while executing Solr start command
> for instan ce: [name: default, port: 8983]
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFacto
> ry.java:317)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.bui
> ldSelf(HybrisContextFactory.java:189)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.bui
> ld(HybrisContextFactory.java:175)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstanceCached(H
> ybrisContextHolder.java:134)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstance(HybrisC
> ontextHolder.java:113)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.getSingletonGlobalApplicationContext
> (Registry.java:1059)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.JMXBeanLoader.getMBeanRegistry(JMXBeanLoader.
> java:155)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.JMXBeanLoader.beforeTenantShutDown(JMXBeanLoa
> der.java:116)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.notifyTenantListenersBeforeShu
> tdown(AbstractTenant.java:1236)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doShutdown(AbstractTenant.java
> :987)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doShutDown(AbstractTenant.java
> :948)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.destroy(Registry.java:309)
>         at de.hybris.platform.util.RedeployUtilities.shutdown(RedeployUtilities.
> java:74)
>         at de.hybris.platform.util.RedeployUtilities$1.run(RedeployUtilities.jav
> a:38) error notifying tenant listener : null
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at de.hybris.platform.jalo.JaloConnection$AbstractSynchronizedPropertyGe
> tter.get(JaloConnection.java:1142)
>         at de.hybris.platform.jalo.JaloConnection.getExtensionManager(JaloConnec
> tion.java:1084)
>         at de.hybris.platform.mobileservices.jalo.MobileManager.getInstance(Mobi
> leManager.java:130)
>         at de.hybris.platform.mobileservices.jalo.MobileManager$1.beforeTenantSh
> utDown(MobileManager.java:92)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.notifyTenantListenersBeforeShu
> tdown(AbstractTenant.java:1236)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doShutdown(AbstractTenant.java
> :987)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doShutDown(AbstractTenant.java
> :948)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.destroy(Registry.java:309)
>         at de.hybris.platform.util.RedeployUtilities.shutdown(RedeployUtilities.
> java:74)
>         at de.hybris.platform.util.RedeployUtilities$1.run(RedeployUtilities.jav
> a:38) INFO  [Thread-1] [HybrisContextFactory] Initializing <<global>>
> Spring Applicati onContext took: (22.52 I¼s) ERROR [Thread-1]
> [RegionCacheAdapter] Unable to clear cache. Failed on region nu ll.
> Last key null null org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException:
> Context hybris Global Context Fact ory  couldn't  be created correctly
> due to, Error creating bean with name 'defau ltSolrServerService'
> defined in class path resource [global-solrserver-spring.xm l]:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> de.hybris.platform.sol rserver.SolrServerException: Error while
> executing Solr start command for instan ce: [name: default, port:
> 8983]
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFacto
> ry.java:317)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.bui
> ldSelf(HybrisContextFactory.java:189)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.bui
> ld(HybrisContextFactory.java:175)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstanceCached(H
> ybrisContextHolder.java:134)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstance(HybrisC
> ontextHolder.java:113)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.getSingletonGlobalApplicationContext
> (Registry.java:1059)
>         at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.getController(Region
> CacheAdapter.java:76)
>         at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.clear(RegionCacheAda
> pter.java:288)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.shutdownCache(AbstractTenant.j
> ava:1061)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doShutdown(AbstractTenant.java
> :1003)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doShutDown(AbstractTenant.java
> :948)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.destroy(Registry.java:309)
>         at de.hybris.platform.util.RedeployUtilities.shutdown(RedeployUtilities.
> java:74)
>         at de.hybris.platform.util.RedeployUtilities$1.run(RedeployUtilities.jav
> a:38) org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Context hybris
> Global Context Fact ory  couldn't  be created correctly due to, Error
> creating bean with name 'defau ltSolrServerService' defined in class
> path resource [global-solrserver-spring.xm l]: Invocation of init
> method failed; nested exception is de.hybris.platform.sol
> rserver.SolrServerException: Error while executing Solr start command
> for instan ce: [name: default, port: 8983]
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFacto
> ry.java:317)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.bui
> ldSelf(HybrisContextFactory.java:189)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.bui
> ld(HybrisContextFactory.java:175)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstanceCached(H
> ybrisContextHolder.java:134)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstance(HybrisC
> ontextHolder.java:113)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.getSingletonGlobalApplicationContext
> (Registry.java:1059)
>         at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.getController(Region
> CacheAdapter.java:76)
>         at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.clear(RegionCacheAda
> pter.java:288)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.shutdownCache(AbstractTenant.j
> ava:1061)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doShutdown(AbstractTenant.java
> :1003)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doShutDown(AbstractTenant.java
> :948)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.destroy(Registry.java:309)
>         at de.hybris.platform.util.RedeployUtilities.shutdown(RedeployUtilities.
> java:74)
>         at de.hybris.platform.util.RedeployUtilities$1.run(RedeployUtilities.jav
> a:38) INFO  [Thread-1] [HybrisContextFactory] Initializing <<global>>
> Spring Applicati onContext took: (10.27 I¼s) ERROR [Thread-1]
> [RegionCacheAdapter] Unable to clear cache. Failed on region nu ll.
> Last key null null org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException:
> Context hybris Global Context Fact ory  couldn't  be created correctly
> due to, Error creating bean with name 'defau ltSolrServerService'
> defined in class path resource [global-solrserver-spring.xm l]:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> de.hybris.platform.sol rserver.SolrServerException: Error while
> executing Solr start command for instan ce: [name: default, port:
> 8983]
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFacto
> ry.java:317)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.bui
> ldSelf(HybrisContextFactory.java:189)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.bui
> ld(HybrisContextFactory.java:175)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstanceCached(H
> ybrisContextHolder.java:134)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstance(HybrisC
> ontextHolder.java:113)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.getSingletonGlobalApplicationContext
> (Registry.java:1059)
>         at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.getController(Region
> CacheAdapter.java:76)
>         at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.clear(RegionCacheAda
> pter.java:288)
>         at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.destroy(RegionCacheA
> dapter.java:521)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.shutdownCache(AbstractTenant.j
> ava:1071)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doShutdown(AbstractTenant.java
> :1003)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doShutDown(AbstractTenant.java
> :948)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.destroy(Registry.java:309)
>         at de.hybris.platform.util.RedeployUtilities.shutdown(RedeployUtilities.
> java:74)
>         at de.hybris.platform.util.RedeployUtilities$1.run(RedeployUtilities.jav
> a:38) org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException: Context hybris
> Global Context Fact ory  couldn't  be created correctly due to, Error
> creating bean with name 'defau ltSolrServerService' defined in class
> path resource [global-solrserver-spring.xm l]: Invocation of init
> method failed; nested exception is de.hybris.platform.sol
> rserver.SolrServerException: Error while executing Solr start command
> for instan ce: [name: default, port: 8983]
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory.build(HybrisContextFacto
> ry.java:317)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.bui
> ldSelf(HybrisContextFactory.java:189)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextFactory$GlobalContextFactory.bui
> ld(HybrisContextFactory.java:175)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstanceCached(H
> ybrisContextHolder.java:134)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.HybrisContextHolder.getGlobalInstance(HybrisC
> ontextHolder.java:113)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.getSingletonGlobalApplicationContext
> (Registry.java:1059)
>         at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.getController(Region
> CacheAdapter.java:76)
>         at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.clear(RegionCacheAda
> pter.java:288)
>         at de.hybris.platform.cache.impl.RegionCacheAdapter.destroy(RegionCacheA
> dapter.java:521)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.shutdownCache(AbstractTenant.j
> ava:1071)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doShutdown(AbstractTenant.java
> :1003)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.AbstractTenant.doShutDown(AbstractTenant.java
> :948)
>         at de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.destroy(Registry.java:309)
>         at de.hybris.platform.util.RedeployUtilities.shutdown(RedeployUtilities.
> java:74)
>         at de.hybris.platform.util.RedeployUtilities$1.run(RedeployUtilities.jav
> a:38) INFO  [Thread-1] [DefaultClusterNodeManagementService]
> Unregistering assigned cl uster node id 0... <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

**UPDATE / SOLUTION: The problem is SOLR Server does not allow spaces in directories.**

Comment: Whenever you install Hybris suit, just make sure your path should be crisp and does not have spaces. Long directory path will also create the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, check all your environment variables if they are correct. Especially `JAVA_HOME` if it has the correct path. If you still have problems, try stopping the SOLR server: `ant stopSolrServer` . You can also stop solr from auto-start by adding this in your .properties file.

```
solrserver.instances.default.autostart=false
```

You can also try changing the default port

```
solrserver.instances.default.port=8984
```

Comment: Where would I put the settings mentioned?
In core's *.properties?

Comment: In your /config folder in file local.properties.

Comment: Found out what's wrong. It seems the server does not allow directory name with spaces, for Solr. Why is it designed like that, quite peculiar.

Comment: This is usually done for unix system, where spaces in directory names is a bad practice and in general a bad naming convention.

Comment: With regards to this solution: `solrserver.instances.default.autostart=false`, it will prevent search from functioning and products from displaying on the StoreFront and BackOffice.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue occure in my case, And i checked, due to some wrong pull or during checkout to different branch, i lost my solr.xml file.

Try to add it back, it will work

Comment: add it back how?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue in my 6.2 setup , finally able to resolve this.
This happens due to specifically two JAR that are 'Jackson-core and Jackson-annotations ' ,these jar need to update with their latest versions  ( i replaced with the versions 2.9.2)
This resolved the issue for me !

Answer (score 0):

Same error occurred for me due to previous solr server was still occupying the port 8983. I tried stopping solrserver but it did not help then I used the following command to list all the open ports:

```
lsof -PiTCP -sTCP:LISTEN
```

and then killed the java pid which was listening on 8983.

```
kill <pid>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes. I did. Added solrserver.instances.default.autostart=false under my config folder in file local.properties. It worked for me.